# Error with call of WinApi GetVersionExA function: Error A2114 INVOKE argument type mismatch : argument : 1

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm

I need to call the [GetVersionExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexa) function from the program written on `masm`. it accepts a single parameter `lpVersionInformation` of the type `LPOSVERSIONINFOA`. Where `LPOSVERSIONINFOA` as i suppose is the instance of [_OSVERSIONINFOA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-osversioninfoa) struct.
So i wrote this simple program but got following error:

```
Error   A2114   INVOKE argument type mismatch : argument : 1 
                                                            main.asm    24
```

I do not know what is wrong and how to fix it.

```
.586
    .model flat, STDCALL
    option casemap :none
    include \masm32\include\windows.inc
    include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
    include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc
    include \masm32\include\user32.inc
    include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
    include \masm32\include\Advapi32.inc
    includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
    includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
    includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
    includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
    includelib \masm32\lib\Advapi32.lib
    .data
    params OSVERSIONINFOA  <>
    buf db 100 dup(?),0
    titl1 db '№ 5 ', 0
    ifmt db "Info = %d %d %d %d %d %c",0dh,0ah,0ah,0
    .code
    Start:
    invoke GetVersionEx, params ; <================================ 24

    invoke wsprintf,ADDR buf,ADDR ifmt,params.dwOSVersionInfoSize,params.dwMajorVersion ,params.dwMinorVersion ,params.dwBuildNumber ,params.dwPlatformId ,params.szCSDVersion
    invoke MessageBox, NULL, ADDR buf, ADDR titl1, MB_OK
    invoke ExitProcess, 0 
    end Start
```

Comment: In addition to the pointer of params, *[GetVersionEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexa) may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the [Version Helper functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/version-helper-apis).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPOSVERSIONINFOA` is a *pointer* to an `OSVERSIONINFOA`. So, just as `wsprintf()` takes the *address* of an allocated `char[]` array to write into for returning its output string, `GetVersionEx()` takes the *address* of an allocated `OSVERSIONINFOA` to write into for returning its version data.

Also, you need to set the `OSVERSIONINFOA.dwOSVersionInfoSize` field before calling `GetVersonEx()`, so it knows whether you are passing it the *address* of an instance of `OSVERSIONINFOA` or `OSVERSIONINFOEXA` (which have different sizes and fields).